# Can I ride faster with a bike jersey?

Tags: clothes, speed

I normally wear a cotton t-shirt when I ride. If I get a bike jersey, how much difference will the reduced air resistance make at, for example, 20 mph? I realize it's not possible to be precise, but I am wondering how much difference it makes.

Comment: The biggest difference is that you'll FEEL faster.  Assuming the fit is roughly equivalent, the viscosity of air is sufficiently low that the difference in texture is negligible.

Comment: Aside - hikers/trampers know that "cotton kills" and they avoid wearing it while walking, because its thermal properties change for the worse when it gets wet, from rain or sweat.  Wool for example will retain its warming properties when wet, cotton does not.  Cotton is fine for the campsite though.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, you will not ride faster in any meaningful way unless you're doing time trials at an elite level where mere seconds (or less) of improvement are gained through optimizing a long list of equipment (with clothing in the middle of that list). As always, the overwhelming determinant of performance is training.

The real reason for wearing a jersey is the following:

- Sweat management. Wicking fabric has to lie against to the skin to actually wick the sweat and transport it to the exterior where the wind will evaporate it quickly.
- Pockets in rear. Pockets are useful. The only place you can reasonably put them is in back.
- Long rear. It looks better when you're hunched over the bike.
- A zipper. So you can regulate temperature.
- Fitted + Flat seams. Flapping fabric is annoying on a ride and seams tend to painfully rub on long rides.

Comment: As an anecodote of how well wicking stuff wicks, I was rinsing my jersey after my morning ride in, and it was still fully wet when I put it on at the end of the day to ride home.

Comment: Within 2 blocks, in the heat, with a breeze, I am dry as a bone.  Then to give an anecdote of how much I sweat, by the end I am soaked again!  So I am sweating faster than it can dry, considering it can go from fully soaked to dry in 2 blocks!

Comment: +1: I'd add visibility too

Answer (score 13):

[This page](http://sheldonbrown.com/rinard/aero/aerodynamics.htm) contains a table with improvements that can be made with various aero clothing and equipment. Unfortunately the baseline is already a cycling jersey, not a standard cotton t-shirt. Given the improvements that clothing can provide though I would suggest the bike jersey would make a pretty big difference.

For me, though the big improvement is in comfort. A sweat wicking jersey is so much more comfortable than a wet, heavy cotton t-shirt.

Comment: Fascinating article, 19% aero difference between the regular shorts + sleeveless T-shirt and jeans + T-Shirt. Makes me want to know some real statistics...

Comment: Note, however, that to see the difference of 10's of seconds it requires performing a time trial for ~1hr at a speed >22mph (37Kph).

Comment: @Angelo: Since air resistance increases as a square, that means that at a typical commuter pace of 11mph you could expect maybe 1 or 2 seconds shaved off of the same 22 mile distance.

Comment: That is an interesting page! No wonder I see partial disk wheels and aero helmets in triathlons.

Answer (score 7):

There are several differences between a plain cotton t-shirt and a cycling jersey. @Mac has already highlighted the sweat wicking potential. Some jerserys are tailored, so they'll certainly be more comfortable and possible aero-dynamic.

After all a tight t-shirt won't necessarily be worse aero-dynamically - it might flap around less, aside from the different flow properties of the chosen materials.

Many jerseys have other attributes though: pockets, zips, reflective strips, longer backs - all of these things might help make other aspects of your attire more stream-lined.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to be precise, [this page](http://sheldonbrown.com/rinard/aero/formulas.htm) originally by Rainer Pivit but found on the excellent [Sheldon Brown](http://sheldonbrown.com) site has the relevant formula.

In short - the effort required to reach and maintain a given speed is a combination of overcoming the forces of gravity, friction and wind resistance.  The key factor in reducing wind resistance is minimizing the frontal area of the bike and the rider. A tight, form fitting t-shirt or cycling jersey will provide some benefit, and will reduce the 'parachute' effect of flapping clothing. But at the rates of speed we are talking about for recreational or utility cycling, the impact will be minimal.